# Determining max value prior to specific incident in data in R

Tags: r

I have some force/time data for jumping tasks where anytime the force value = 0, they are in the air. I am looking for peak force during the propulsion phase of the jump, so before it reads 0 or less than 0. I can't just use the max() function because landing force is almost always greater than propulsion force. I don't want to trim the data, because max landing force is another variable of interest. I don't want to do this manually because I will have a large sample. Any ideas how I can return the max value for the propulsion force or max value prior to force values of 0? Thanks

Here's some sample data (the real data collects at 1000 data points per second, so I had to just make something similar to the force/time curve here). So here I would be looking for the max value prior to 0 or 10s.
[example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ExcE3.png)

Comment: When asking for help, you should include a [reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) with sample input data and the desired output for that input. This makes it much easier to help you because we are able to verify and test possible solutions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to find the maximum value for the set of values the occur before the first value that is less than 10, try the following:

```
myMax <- max(x[1:(which(x < 10)[1]-1)])
```

Comment: Perfect! Thank you